# CRM 2011 - Custom entity error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a custom entity, and updated the javascript from CRM 4 to 2011.

However when the form loads i recieve this error:

> There was an error with this fields customized event.
>
> Field:window
>
> Event:onload
>
> Error:Unable to get value of the property '1': object is null or
>   undefined.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Add some code in question....

Answer (score 2):

Use F12 to open up the developer tools and track down the error.  You've got a javascript error of some type on the form...

Answer (score 1):

Use Debugger statement in your java script and debug it.